# Divider on ionic 2 not working

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I've been struggling to do an divider after movie name and before movie genre (as you can see in the screenshot uploaded)..

I tried using an ion-list and using `< ion-item class="item-divider">`.. didnt work. 
I also tried using the `hr` html tag inside a `div`, but it only works on browser simulating android devices.. when I switch to ios devices it doesn't work very well..

Can anyone help me please?
PS.: This is ionic2.. on ionic1 I think it still works

[image]

Comment: Which version ionic1 or ionic2?

Comment: why was I tagged in this question? @jpfrr

Comment: @XYZ Like said on question, its ionic 2

Comment: @jpfrr `<ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider color="light">A</ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item>Angola</ion-item>
    <ion-item>Argentina</ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>` try like this